# Can we use the Metropolis-Hastings with a discretized proposal?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Consider the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal density $q(x,y)$ and target density $p(y)$ with respect to some reference measure $\lambda$. If we don't use the proposals $Y\sim q(x,\;\cdot\;)\lambda$ directly, but replace them with $\lfloor Y\rfloor$, is there such a variant of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm (most probably with a suitably modified acceptance probability) which still works?

Comment: If the target density is supported by the real line, a proposal supported by the integers cannot work.

Comment: @Xi'an What I thought about is the following: Couldn't we create proposals on $[0,1)^2\cap\varepsilon\mathbb Z^2$ and show that this still works as $\varepsilon\to0+$? (Maybe related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk#Two_dimensions)

Comment: If you pick $\epsilon$ as the machine precision, this would be equivalent to the original but then where's the advantage / appeal??

Comment: @Xi'an Even when $\varepsilon$ is not the machine epsilon, shouldn't we end up with an approximate estimate? The reason why I'm interested in this is that this would allow us to enforce a minimum distance between the samples.

Comment: However, $[0,1)^2\cap\varepsilon\mathbb Z^2$ is a regular grid. I'd like to have a more "random" walk like the ones you can see in the first row of figure 1 in this paper: http://abdallagafar.com/abdalla/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Continuous-Line-Based-Halftoning-with-Pinwheel-Tiles.pdf